# Python - Make a Dictionary with a variable number of keys/values

Tags: python, dictionary, variadic-functions

Okay, the title is a bit confusing, but let me elaborate.

Some methods in Java have a useful thing called `varargs` that allow for varying amounts of arguments in methods. It looks something like this:

```
void method(String... args) {
    for (String arg : args) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

I am trying to learn Python through a course, and one of the assignments is asking me to take a CSV file with a **varying** amount of Strings at the top that represents repeating sequences of DNA in a strand. Here's an example:

```
name,AGATC,AATG,TATC
Alice,2,8,3
```

However, they also offer different CSV files that have differing amounts of DNA sequences to check for, like the example below:

```
name,AGATC,TTTTTTCT,AATG,TCTAG,GATA,TATC,GAAA,TCTG
Jason,15,49,38,5,14,44,14,12
```

(the numbers equate to how many of the above DNA sequences are repeated in their strand. So Jason has 15 AGATC repetitions in this strand)

I want to use a Dictionary variable to store the name and all their repetitions in it. However, since I don't know in advance how many DNA sequences I'll have to check for, the Dictionary has to be programmed with any number of those sequences in mind. **Is there a way to use something similar to Java's `varargs` in a Python `Dictionary`?**

The output format I want is to convert the group of people and their repetitions inside the DNA database into a List that contains a Dictionary that equates to each person. Because the CSV file can contain a variable number of DNA sequences (as shown above), I want to have each person's Dictionary have their name as their first key, then an additional amount of keys for each DNA Sequence in the CSV file. Here's an example that adheres to the snippet of the CSV file above:
`{"name": "Jason", "seq1": 15, "seq2": 49, "seq3": 38, "seq4": 5, "seq5": 14, "seq6": 4, "seq7": 14, "seq8": 12}`

Comment: Python dicts are mutable, so you can add as many key/value pairs as you want. You don't need to pre-allocate space in Python.

Comment: Python has varargs: `def method(*args):`. You could just pass in a list too. I don't see the relevance between `varargs` and what you're trying to do though.

Comment: What's your desired output? I don't know Java, but I can show you how to get what you want in Python.

Comment: Have a look at [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) for a direct way to do that.

Comment: wjandrea I edited the post to include the output format that I'm aiming for

Comment: @JNSStudios_YT, so you are not using the strings like `AGATC` as dict keys -- just a sequence number? If so, why not use a list `seq` and then index into it with `seq[1]`, `seq[2]`, etc. This is a more natural way to hold data where order is significant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*args` to get a list containing all the arguments

```
def my_seq(*args): 
    for arg in args: 
        print (arg)
   
my_seq('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

Comment: `*args` is the customary name. `argv` usually only refers to command-line arguments in Python.

Answer (score 0):

*All* Python dictionaries have a variable number of items, since they're mutable, so this is a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832), but to get what you want, you can use a [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) (as [Thierry Lathuille](https://stackoverflow.com/users/550094/thierry-lathuille) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64092197/python-make-a-dictionary-with-a-variable-number-of-keys-values/64092288#comment113336276_64092197)).

Let's call your first example `example1.csv`:

```
name,AGATC,AATG,TATC
Alice,2,8,3
```

To read it, you can do something like this:

```
import csv

with open('example1.csv') as f:
    rows = list(csv.DictReader(f))

print(rows)
# -> [{'name': 'Alice', 'AGATC': '2', 'AATG': '8', 'TATC': '3'}]
```

The numbers aren't automatically converted to ints, but you could use a dict comprehension:

```
rows = [
    {k: v if k == 'name' else int(v) for k, v in row.items()}
    for row in rows
    ]
print(rows)
# -> [{'name': 'Alice', 'AGATC': 2, 'AATG': 8, 'TATC': 3}]
```

Note that the DNA sequences themselves will probably be more useful as keys than `'seq1'`, `'seq2'`, etc. For example if you read in your other CSV as `rows2`, you can then do set-like operations on the keys:

```
>>> alice = rows[0]
>>> jason = rows2[0]
>>> len(alice.keys() - jason.keys())  # How many keys are unique to Alice?
0
>>> jason.keys() - alice.keys()  # What keys does Jason have that Alice doesn't?
{'TCTAG', 'GATA', 'TCTG', 'TTTTTTCT', 'GAAA'}
```

---

If you want to get really advanced, you can use a [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) DataFrame. Here's just a short example, cause I'm not very familiar with it myself :)

```
import pandas as pd

files = 'example2.csv', 'example1.csv'  # Note the order
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, index_col="name") for f in files]
df = pd.concat(dfs, sort=False)
df = df.astype('Int64')  # allow ints and NaN in the same column

print(df)
```

Output:

```
       AGATC  TTTTTTCT  AATG  TCTAG  GATA  TATC  GAAA  TCTG
name                                                       
Jason     15        49    38      5    14    44    14    12
Alice      2       NaN     8    NaN   NaN     3   NaN   NaN
```